# is arcsin() evenly distributed?

Tags: uniform-distribution

Given a uniform random distribution P of real numbers from [0,1] how might I prove (or disprove) that the map from P to Q of $(p\in{P} \rightarrow  q=arcsin(p)\in{Q}) $ is a uniform distribution over [0,$\pi$]?

Comment: As an aside, I think my notation might be awkward, so advice on wording this better is welcome as well.

Comment: Do you intend to say $\arcsin$ instead?

Comment: Disprove is easier. One can find explicitly the distribution, which is not uniform on $(0,\sin(1))$. Same with any reasonable change in the problem.

Comment: I did intend to say arcsin! Thank you. Does this change your response Andre?

Comment: No change. Note however that if $p$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, then $\arcsin(p)$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$. But it is not uniformly distributed in that interval.

Comment: You can find discussion of a certain probability distribution under a heading "the arcsine law"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a uniform distribution, the probability that a points lands on a interval depends only on the length of the interval.

Consider the intervals $A=[0,h]$ and $B=[\frac{\pi}{2}-h,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, which have the same length $h>0$.

The probability that $p$ lands on $A$ is higher than
the probability that $p$ lands on $B$, because $\sin(A)$ has length $\sin(h)$ but $\sin(B)$ has length $1-\cos(h)$ and $\sin(h) > 1-\cos(h)$ for $0 < h < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem in the question ... it was supposed to say arcsin() not sin() ...

Comment: @DanielB., my answer is about arcsin. The use of sin here is just a convenient way to express the inverse image of arcsin.